# firebase Objects are not valid as a React child, If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a react app with firebase. when I tried to retrieve my messages from the database I was getting the following error

"Objects are not valid as a React child, If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

My code

```
const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('channels').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setChannels(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                channel: doc.data()
            }))
        )
    );
}, [])
```

my component render

```
 {channels.map(({ channel, id }) => (
                    <SidebarChannel
                        key={id}
                        id={id}
                        channelName={channel}
                    />
                ))}
```

output

```
 channels[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: This error is probably caused by your component's return/render function. Post it here to get more help.

Comment: Yes, please add your component implementation, feels like it should be as simple as writing somewhere `{channels[0]}` which would render an object

Comment: what is the structure of the channel? it seems its not an array ....

Comment: console.log(typeof channels)

Answer (score 1):

So, anything you output in JSX (in your render function) must be a valid react child (text, number, HTML nodes..) or an array of valid react child.

So since React is telling you "Objects are not valid as a React child, If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

That means something that you are rendering is an object, instead of a text, number or array.

If it's not channel then look into the SidebarChannel component and check the for the same issue.